# Add CA certificate to node docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, dockerfile

I am dockerizing my node.js app, in my Dockerfile I pull from the official node image: https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

I get the following error when I try to install my dependencies:

```
{
code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN',
errno: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
type: 'system'
}
```

I tried this answer, but it did not solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47455064/15104234

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app


COPY my_cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
RUN update-ca-certificates


# Install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Copy app source
COPY . .

# Expose app port
EXPOSE 3000

# Start app
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```